# Is there a way to hide the content block until one of the tabs is clicked; Hidden after page load, visible when tabs are clicked?

Tags: html, css, tabs, width, display

`I'm fairly new to programming and this site but I've been studying different codes for vertical and horizontal tabs and there's a question I want to ask regarding this one    https://jsfiddle.net/eu81273/812ehkyf/ :

Is there a way to hide the content block until one of the tabs is clicked; Hidden after page load, visible when tabs are clicked? 
I understand it can be hidden using `display: none;` but how do I make it reappear when tabs are clicked? Or am I completely wrong?

It would be nice if a detailed explanation is provided on the changes or additions so I can understand it well.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You have two distinct questions in your question. In SO, we try to have exactly one unique question per question. Can you edit your question to contain just one question and post the other question as another separate question?

Comment: @KevinJohnson Done, apologies!